# SMS spoofing in the US

Tags: spoofing, sms

Long story short(ish), I have a friend who's been in a relationship with this girl for a while. When they started she had just moved across country and was in something open with some other dude. She decided she wanted to stay here with my friend and then he received a threatening text from the other guy's number. Well we finally convinced her to check the other guy's phone logs from the actual carrier website and they show he didn't send them from his device at least. So I'm looking for provable possibilities as to how he did it and hopefully how my friend possibly couldn't have.

From my understanding sms spoofing in the US is pretty tricky and the most likely possibility would be that this other guy gave a friend his permission to use his number.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding sms spoofing in the US is pretty tricky.

Your understanding is incorrect. Spoofing of both *sender ID* in SMS & *caller ID* in phone calls are trivial.

E.g., Crissy Joshua [explains](https://us.norton.com/blog/mobile/sms-spoofing) on Norton's blog:

> Spoofing text messages works by altering the sender’s name or phone number so that the message appears to be coming from someone else. There are hundreds of text spoofer apps that make this possible. Spoofing can be done for legitimate purposes, like a bank displaying their name instead of the phone number they use, or for nefarious purposes such as online scams.

According to *Federal Communications Commission*s article on [Caller ID Spoofing](https://www.fcc.gov/spoofing), the countermeasure in US seems to be investigating a possible spoofing afterwards rather than trying to prevent it.

> Spoofing is when a caller deliberately falsifies the information transmitted to your caller ID display to disguise their identity. Scammers often use neighbor spoofing so it appears that an incoming call is coming from a local number, or spoof a number from a company or a government agency that you may already know and trust.
>
> --
>
> If you think you've been the victim of a spoofing scam, you can file a complaint with the FCC.

In Finland, preventing caller ID spoofing of Finnish phone numbers has been [recommended](https://www.kyberturvallisuuskeskus.fi/sites/default/files/media/regulation/EN%20Recommendation%20to%20Telecommunications%20Operators%20on%20Detecting%20and%20Preventing%20Caller%20ID%20Spoofing.pdf) by the *Finnish Transport and Communications Agency Traficom* and [regulated](https://www.traficom.fi/en/regulations/regulation-28-interoperability-communications-networks-and-services) since July 2022 for landlines and from October 2023 for mobile numbers. As there is technology for this, I wish it becomes more common & global in the future.

Comment: Then whats all this about? https://www.reddit.com/r/blackhat/comments/w1qc1l/sms_spoofing_in_the_us/
I have been unable to find any service that allows for sms spoofing in the US. It appears to be treated differently from call spoofing.

Comment: I think it is the difference between being _illegal_ and being _technically possible_. That's why it's not provided as a service, but there are applications for it. Criminals do not care about the legality.

Comment: Yeah I do understand that. But im trying to prove that with anything less than a cia level hack it is not possible to spoof a text without the persons permission. I've tried every app and online service I can find and non of them offer it. 

In the us carriers have to register with the sms service and if they are found to be delivering spoofed texts then they are in big trouble. So while possible you would have to set up a fake carrier and some how get access to the sms system. 

Maybe im way off the mark but after weeks of searching this is what ive come to understand